# Copy blocks of rows based on specific rule

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

long time reader, first time poster. I have exhausted my research skills and need some expert help please.

I have a spreadsheet that we use to record locations (anything up to 50,000) for uploading into a standalone system. The upload cannot cope with xlsm so I need to copy it to a fresh worksheet (which I have done) however, it also cannot cope with more than 5,000 records at a time so...

I need to amend my vba to look at how many records there are on the xlsm sheet and copy the first 5,000, then the second 5,000 and so on if needs be.
This formula calaculates the number of 5,000 blocks:

```
=CEILING(COUNTA(Table1[Country Name])/5000,1)
```

And this is the vba currently working for less than 5,000:

```
Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Move
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

I'm still quite a basic user in relation to vba so a lot of my vba codes are cobbled together from numerous posts found on this site and others.

Thanks in advance for your help.

MMS

Comment: Could you not just save it as a .xlsx workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the whole Worksheet. Right Click on your sheet -> select move or copy.. then select the workbook you want it copied too.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create worksheets in your new workbook, each holding batches of 5,000 rows, and then export one sheet at a time?

The code below is an example of how you could do it. Note, there's no error handling in it so you'd need to make sure that 1) both workbooks are open in same application, 2) the raw data is in the same workbook as your VBA, and 3) there is data on your raw data sheet.

```
Const OUTPUT_BOOK_NAME As String = "OutputBook.xlsx" 'rename to your workbook
Const RAWDATA_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1" 'rename to your sheet
Const START_ROW As Long = 3 'ammend row ref if different
Const MAX_RECORDS As Integer = 5000

Dim outputBook As Workbook
Dim outputSht As Worksheet
Dim rawdataSht As Worksheet
Dim endRow As Long
Dim endCol As Long
Dim iterations As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Long
Dim v As Variant

'Check the output workbook is open
Set outputBook = Workbooks(OUTPUT_BOOK_NAME)

'Find worksheet limits
Set rawdataSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(RAWDATA_SHEET_NAME)
endRow = rawdataSht.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                               After:=rawdataSht.Cells(1), _
                               Lookat:=xlPart, _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                               MatchCase:=False).Row

endCol = rawdataSht.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                               After:=rawdataSht.Cells(1), _
                               Lookat:=xlPart, _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                               MatchCase:=False).Column

'Round up number of splits in data required.
iterations = -Int((endRow - START_ROW) / -MAX_RECORDS)

'Copy batches of 5000 to the next workbook
For i = 0 To iterations - 1
    r = i * MAX_RECORDS + START_ROW
    v = rawdataSht.Cells(r, 1).Resize(MAX_RECORDS, endCol).Value2
    Set outputSht = outputBook.Worksheets.Add(After:=outputBook.Worksheets(outputBook.Worksheets.Count))
    outputSht.Name = CStr(i * MAX_RECORDS + 1) & " - " & CStr((i + 1) * MAX_RECORDS)
    outputSht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(MAX_RECORDS, endCol).value = v
Next
```